# Beginner - using datatables server-side processing with django

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x, datatable, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Django & web dev and looking for guidance on getting server-side processing working with my datatable.

Basically, I have an external .db SQLite file with 500k records and I would like to display the records on a bootstrap datatable.

In my views.py file, whenever they visit index.html, I make a query statement to fetch the records (not sure if that's inefficient but it's a small hobby website)

```
groups = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM PlayerGroups""")
return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'groups': groups}) # the issue since it returns 500k records which is too much for the client to handle.
```

I understand I need to put something like this in "index.html":

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": <confused about this part...>
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm confused about making my own database API and linking the ajax source to my views/urls file. All of the guides I've looked online show server-side processing with models and stuff. I just have a external .db file I want to show on a datatable.

Any guidance or help would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't want to query and display 500,000 records. That's too heavy for both frontend and backend. One solution is pagination.

Divide frontend into pages. Each page displays a fixed number, 10 for example, of records. When users request the first page, query the first 10 records in your db table. When users request the next page, query the next 10 records. And so on.

You can accomplish that using sqlite LIMIT and OFFSET clauses

```
SELECT
 id, name
FROM
 table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET offset;
```

where `offset = page_number * 10`.